# Appropriateness of two spaces inbetween words

Tags: grammar, spacing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many spaces should come after a period/full stop?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2544/how-many-spaces-should-come-after-a-period-full-stop)

I understand the justification for reverting to a single-space system (computers aren't typewriters), but is it *actually* inappropriate to use two spaces after a period?  I always learned to write that way, and look at a single-space paper and feel kind of... claustrophobic.

Comment: What do you mean with _two spaces between a word_?

Comment: Do you mean after a full stop?  Typographers are fussy about that and hate double spaces, but I think it is more a matter of personal style.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2544/how-many-spaces-should-come-after-a-period-full-stop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a bit confused at what you mean. There are three interpretations of your question:

1. The traditional two spaces after a period, which has to do with typewriters. This is ok, but it just looks unnatural with current technology, since most new fonts have special ways to put in extra space.

   > ```
   > This is a sentence.  There are two spaces between a period and the next sentence.
   > ```
2. Double spacing in paragraphs and essays, which is what it sounds like you might be talking about in your last sentence. This is also ok; it makes papers much easier to read.

   > This is a sentence. At the end of this line, we skip
   >
   > a line before continuing. This stops papers from
   >
   > looking like they're too dense.
3. Two spaces between each and every word. This is highly not recommended; modern font designers deliberately choose a space width that looks appropriate for the font. The only reason to do so is because of poor [kerning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) by the font designer that makes two words look like one. This is because a space is between two words; using an extra one defeats the purpose.

   > ```
   > This  type  of  spacing  is  unnatural  and  not correct.
   > Instead, this natural spacing looks better.
   > ```
   >
   > And when I take it into a non-fixed-width font, it looks even better.

Comment: Right, sorry, I guess my question was more than a little unclear.  What I was referring to was the double spacing after a period, which I've always been taught to do.  Your explanation makes sense though, cheers.