# Punctuation placement in speech

Tags: punctuation, quotations, periods, question-mark

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is it ever acceptable for a period to come after a quote at the end of a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23/is-it-ever-acceptable-for-a-period-to-come-after-a-quote-at-the-end-of-a-sentence)
>   [How much punctuation is appropriate when ending a sentence with a full-sentence quotation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166/how-much-punctuation-is-appropriate-when-ending-a-sentence-with-a-full-sentence-q)

If I have a sentence where I  double quote what someone says, i.e.

> The man said "How are you?"

If that was the end of the sentence, does it need a full stop at the end as follows?

> The man said "How are you?"**.**

Comment: See also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166/how-much-punctuation-is-appropriate-when-ending-a-sentence-with-a-full-sentence-q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word, no.  Never put two punctuation marks separated only by a quote mark.  (See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166/how-much-punctuation-is-appropriate-when-ending-a-sentence-with-a-full-sentence-q) , as it appears to be a duplicate.)

Comment: So it's better to write, "How are you?" he asked.

Comment: yes, that's the correct form.