# Quoting a question at the end of a sentence which is itself a question

Tags: punctuation, questions, quotations, question-mark

If my sentence is a question *and* ends with a quote of a question, where exactly do I put a question mark?

> 1. Did she ask, "Is it raining"?
> 2. Did she ask, "Is it raining?"?
> 3. Did she ask, "Is it raining?"

Comment: Related: [How much punctuation is appropriate when ending a sentence with a full-sentence quotation?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The convention here is to write

> Did she ask, "Is it raining?"

with the first question mark included and the second omitted.

See for example Jane Straus's [Blue book of grammar and punctuation](http://grammarbook.com/punctuation/quotes.asp) or Larry Trask's [Guide to punctuation](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/department/docs/punctuation/node45.html#SECTION0001011000000000000000).

Comment: Isn't there a comma before the direct speech, or is that just a typo?

Answer (score 12):

As reported in [Comma sense—a fun-damental guide to punctuation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0739465031) ([Richard Lederer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Lederer) and John Shore, ISBN 0-312-34255-1), the question mark should be used once, and inside the quotation marks.

> Did you hear me ask, "Do you think that I love punctuation?"

If the quoted sentence contain an exclamation point, then both the exclamation point and the question mark are used.

> Did you hear me exclaim, "I love punctuation!"?

Similarly, both the exclamation point and the question mark are used in sentences similar to the following one:

> How wonderful that I asked, "Do you think that I love punctuation?"!

Comment: Your answer is also in conformance with the current Chicago Manual of Style, 16th ed. (2010) section 6.120.

Answer (score 7):

Taken from rules concerning [Question mark usage](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000104.htm) here:

> In the rare case where the question is about a quotation ending in a question, the sentence ends with a single question mark before the quotation mark.
>
> Incorrect: Who said, "Et tu, Bruté?"?
> (Second question mark redundant)
> Correct: Who said, "Et tu, Bruté?"

Thus, for your example, it would be :

> 2.Did she ask, "Is it raining?"

Comment: Brute wasn't a frenchman...

Comment: These are style guide recommendations. I can find an alternative 'allowing' the double question mark in British usage, so labels of 'incorrect' are prescriptive.