# Question mark(s) when asking about a quoted query

Tags: punctuation, question-mark

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quoting a question at the end of a sentence which is itself a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36885/quoting-a-question-at-the-end-of-a-sentence-which-is-itself-a-question)

Although some might say you can't *say* a question, only *ask* it, I assume I *can* say (write)...

> - He said "What's happening, man?".

so if I want to check if that statement is true, logically, shouldn't I write...

> - Did he just say "What's happening, man?"?

My gut instinct is I can't have *two* question marks. So I have to ditch the first one, because the fact that the original is a question is less "important" now the "bigger" question has been asked about it.

I can't think of a good example "original" where the presence or absence of the question mark changes the meaning, but I feel there must be utterances that can be read as a question or a statement, dependent solely on the question mark being there or not. So I don't really want to unilaterally abandon the first one just because there's another coming up real soon.

Comment: @Thursagen: I searched past questions, but didn't find that because I looked for "question mark", and that one doesn't happen to include the word "mark". I'll now see what happens if I vote to close my own question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an applicable rule [in GrammarBook](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/quotes.asp):

> When you have a question outside quoted material AND inside quoted material, use only one question mark and place it inside the
>   quotation mark.
>
> **Example**:   Did she say, "May I go?"

So in your case, your instinct to drop one question mark is correct. The sample sentence you gave should be:

> He said, "What's happening, man?"

Answer (score 0):

[Quote:](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36885/quoting-a-question-at-the-end-of-a-sentence-which-is-itself-a-question/36888#36888)

Taken from rules concerning [Question mark usage](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000104.htm) here:

> In the rare case where the question is about a quotation ending in a question, the sentence ends with a single question mark before the quotation mark.
>
> Incorrect: Who said, "Et tu, Bruté?"?
> (Second question mark redundant)
> Correct: Who said, "Et tu, Bruté?"