# How should the end of a quotation be punctuated?

Tags: punctuation

I was reading a book where the dialogues of the actors were written in paragraphs. The dialogues, were broken down by the author into pieces of sentences, and between the pieces, the author inserted his thoughts/facts/humour, and then proceeded with the dialogue. For example,

*He continued, “Just after the Independence,” and rose from his chair.*

Should this have been typed as **”,** instead of **,”**?

Or take a second example,

*He said, “I am a good boy.”*

This is how it is generally written. But it seems to me that there should be another fullstop at the end of the sentence to mark the end of **He said, “———”.** sentence.

How should inverted commas be closed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it ever acceptable for a period to come after a quote at the end of a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23/is-it-ever-acceptable-for-a-period-to-come-after-a-quote-at-the-end-of-a-sentenc) and [Is it correct to use punctuation outside of the quotations or inside?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5490/is-it-correct-to-use-punctuation-outside-of-the-quotations-or-inside) and [How should I punctuate around quotes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1560/how-should-i-punctuate-around-quotes).

Comment: Hello, Ahmed. (a) Logical (/sensible!?) treatment and established usage/s are often not the same in English // (b) usage**s**: often, with punctuation rules, different styles are recommended by different style guides etc // (c) 'Double punctuation' at the end of a quote is eschewed by many people especially in the US, but is tolerated as a necessary evil especially in the UK // (d) I've tweaked your example (1); both are now acceptable (though 'final punctuation _outside the quote_' is recommended by some on some occasions. (e) this has been covered here before.

Comment: Also relevant: [How do you insert a complete sentence quote into the middle of a sentence...?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127852/how-do-you-insert-a-complete-sentence-quote-into-the-middle-of-a-sentence-before/127853#127853) and [Are full stops placed inside or outside quotation marks?_Tim North](http://www.scribe.com.au) is clear. [AccuAssist_Punctuation and Quotations](http://www.accu-assist.com/grammar-tips-archive/GrammarTip_punctuation-and-quotations-marks-3.htm) may also help.

Comment: Also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73216/punctuation-of-direct-speech-edge-cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Chicago Manual of Style (CMoS, 13th ed.) says in section 5.63:

> A direct quotation, maxim, or similar expression should ordinarily be set off from the rest of the sentence by commas:

- Vera said calmly, "I have no idea what you mean."
- "The driver refused to enter the bus," retorted Eberly.
- "I am afraid," said Kroft, "that I can offer no explanation."
- You know the old saying, Politics makes strange bedfellows.

Your sentence,

- He said, “I am a good boy.”

is correctly punctuated.

Comment: Isn’t it, the quotation sentence is still open, without any closing fullstop? Why not this? *He said, "I'm a good boy.".*

Comment: If I punctuate your example like < *"The driver refused --- .", retorted Eberly.* > this. Isn’t it more logical?

Comment: (It should be obvious, but CMoS is an American English standard.)

Comment: You said, "...the quotation sentence is still open, without any closing fullstop?" The sentence, "I am a good boy" *has* its full stop. It's placed inside the quotation marks by (AmE) convention.

Comment: When I read <"The driver refused to enter the bus.", retorted Eberly.> out loud, my voice went to its lowest point after "bus." Then it lifted a little for the last part, as the sentence did not complete. The retort seemed like an incomplete afterthought.