# Do I use two full stops when embedding a quote in a paragraph?

Tags: punctuation

If I am embedding a quote in a paragraph such as:

Thomas, a scientist, said ‘’I wish I had access to more samples’’

Should I put a full stop inside the quotation marks as well as outside if it’s at the end of a sentence and I am to continue with the paragraph after this sentence?

Which is correct?

Thomas, a scientist, said ‘’I wish I had access to more samples.’’. Thomas has been working hard with a team of scientists to find a cure.

Or

Thomas, a scientist, said ‘’I wish I had access to more samples.’’ Thomas has been working hard with a team of scientists to find a cure.

Which one would be correct in accordance to the rules of British English?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How much punctuation is appropriate when ending a sentence with a full-sentence quotation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166/how-much-punctuation-is-appropriate-when-ending-a-sentence-with-a-full-sentence) I'm quite prepared to double-punctuate where I think it's necessary for clarity. With spoken words, there was no full stop when the words were spoken, so a single full stop should be necessary to show the end of the quote-and-sentence, essentially doing double duty. Often in the UK, this will be inside the inverted commas, after the quote.

Comment: In the context of your Question, 'Thomas said ‘’I wish I had access to more samples.’’ Thomas has (anything)…' would be correct in accordance with the rules of English, anywhere.

That looks like a contrived example.

In other circumstances it might - as Edwin hints above - be appropriate to use one stop in- and another outside the quotation marks… and as so often, circumstances alter cases.