# Where to put the period after a quoted word

Tags: punctuation, quotes

Here is the sentence:
The result of the moisture-laden air entering window assembly is visible condensation or “fog”.

Doesn't the period go after the g?

Comment: Oh, and by the way...welcome to EL&U.

Comment: I like the start of the accepted answer in [that link](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/31757/240807): **...this answer begins with, “it depends”.**

Comment: This is indeed a question of style. If you have a particular style guide to follow, consult that particular style guide. If you don't need to follow a style guide but, say, have to write this for a paper in a particular domain, check other papers from that field, consult your peers or professor. If you don't have to care about any of that, you can pick a style of your own. I.e. do whatever you like, but stick to it consistently throughout.

Comment: @RegDwigнt This is probably the best, and most common sense answer that the OP will get here. The duplicates will argue one way or the other, but... It wasn't until I came here almost 3 years ago that I began to question my own style. I even wasted a lot of time going through some stuff revising them.

Comment: @Cascabel that's the lesson here, innit. Don't second-guess your style. It's called "style" and not "hymn book" for a reason, and it is yours and yours alone to develop and nurture and uphold.

Comment: @Cascabel just before you posted the link in a comment that became a dup, I had written a (now deleted) comment about quoted speech including: *I said "the moisture is called fog."* I was thumbing through a novel looking to see if the quoted speech should begin with a capital **T** when I realised the publisher's style had completely avoided this situation, by placing *I said:* in a paragraph above.

Comment: @Cascabel not that I know of. I removed the comment because your dup was a good answer.