# Question Regarding Punctuation and Quotation Mark

Tags: grammaticality, orthography

I'm struggling to recall the answers to the questions below. Any assistance would be wonderful!
Thanks!

1. Does the comma go inside or outside the quotation mark in the sentence below?

I submitted my article to the academic journal "News Today," where it's currently undergoing the peer review process.

2. Does the period go inside or outside the quotation mark in the sentence below?

I submitted my article to the academic journal "News Today."

Comment: Does this answer your question? Unfortunately, the accepted answer is incomplete and lacking support. It's also wrong in common US style, where the period is normally always inside the closing quotation mark. Only in UK style is the period commonly outside, unless the period is part of what's being quoted. [Where should the period be put when an entire sentence is quoted at the end of a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31750/where-should-the-period-be-put-when-an-entire-sentence-is-quoted-at-the-end-of-a)

Comment: In US style, the comma would also go inside the quotation marks; in UK style, it would commonly go outside the quotation marks.

Comment: I appreciate the responses! So the correct US style would be:

I submitted my article to the academic journal "News Today," where it's currently undergoing the peer review process.

----------

I submitted my article to the academic journal "News Today."

Comment: Yes, that's right.